# How to plot multiple paired dataframe columns in a scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with returns (mean), and standard deviation of four stocks (8 columns in total)

I want to plot all four stocks, using a scatter dot plots, with the y-axis being the returns and the x-axis being the standard deviation in the same plot.

Here is the dataframe that I have:

```
 Dates      AAPL Mean   AAPL STD    AMZN Mean   AMZN STD    GS Mean     GS STD      SP500 Mean  SP500 STD   Portfolio Mean  Portfolio STD           
    2009    0.003819    0.021369    0.004349    0.033053    0.003524    0.038186    0.000983    0.017188    0.003858    0.024681
    2010    0.001832    0.016856    0.001367    0.020573    0.000212    0.019343    0.000542    0.011372    0.001125    0.014509
    2011    0.001040    0.016539    0.000139    0.024192    -0.002127   0.023905    0.000107    0.014661    -0.000313   0.016933
    2012    0.001299    0.018566    0.001680    0.020038    0.001603    0.018009    0.000536    0.008043    0.001512    0.013373
    2013    0.000472    0.017987    0.001985    0.017021    0.001450    0.013557    0.001054    0.006973    0.001289    0.010746
    2014    0.001447    0.013643    -0.000784   0.020297    0.000466    0.010903    0.000454    0.007163    0.000372    0.010869
    2015    0.000020    0.016843    0.003308    0.021147    -0.000138   0.014043    0.000019    0.009760    0.001053    0.013520
    2016    0.000575    0.014702    0.000586    0.018711    0.001332    0.016911    0.000395    0.008249    0.000823    0.012360
    2017    0.001637    0.011091    0.001856    0.013207    0.000374    0.012406    0.000716    0.004212    0.001276    0.008679
    2018    -0.000057   0.018106    0.001256    0.022744    -0.001495   0.016160    -0.000199   0.010741    -0.000098   0.016156
```

- One pair of columns can be plotted with the following code

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(Means['AAPL STD'], Means['AAPL Mean'], 'ob', label = 'AAPL')

plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
plt.xlabel('Annualized Standard Deviation')
plt.ylabel('Annualized Returns')
leg = ax.legend()
```

- How can all of the column pairs be plotted without manually creating each plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make certain `Dates` is set as the index. This will prevent it from being included in the column groups to plot.
- Use a list-comprehension to create groups for each ticker

  - `[a[k:k+n] for k in range(0, len(a), n)]`

    - This works because the ticker columns are adjacent to each other.
  - Plot each group
- To remove `Portfolio` from the plot, use `col_groups[:-1]` instead of `col_groups`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set the Dates column as the index
df.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)

# get the df column name
a = df.columns

# create a list of column names in groups of 2
col_groups = [a[k:k+n] for k in range(0, len(a), 2)]

# setup the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

# iterate through the groups
for y, x in col_groups:

    # plot each group
    plt.scatter(df[x], df[y], label=f'{y.split(" ")[0]}')

# add the legend
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

# add labels
plt.ylabel('Returns')
plt.xlabel('Standard Deviation')

# add a grid
plt.grid()

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Trenton. This is perfect and way efficient. Definitely gonna use this.

Comment: @BilalAmiri You're welcome. I'm glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that works just fine and I am able to plot scatter plots of all the stocks' returns vs standard deviation in one plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(Means['AAPL STD'], Means['AAPL Mean'], 'ob', label = 'AAPL')
ax.plot(Means['AMZN STD'], Means['AMZN Mean'], 'og', label = 'AMZN')
ax.plot(Means['GS STD'], Means['GS Mean'], 'oy', label = 'GS')
ax.plot(Means['SP500 STD'], Means['SP500 Mean'], 'ob', label ='SP500')
ax.plot(Means['Portfolio STD'], Means['Portfolio Mean'], 'or', label ='Portfolio')
plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
plt.xlabel('Annualized Standard Deviation')
plt.ylabel('Annualized Returns')
leg = ax.legend()
```